# How to dynamically construct vertex geometry on the GPU

Tags: three.js, webgl, gpgpu

As a way of teaching myself WebGL and Three.js, I'm building a simple demo/game.  The idea is a 3D version of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYpE8-4_YBk&t=75s - navigate the opening, and don't crash.

What I want to do is create a dynamic "tube" using vertices calculated on the fly, like this:

```
for ( var p = 0 ; p < LIMIT ; p++ ) {
  r = RADIUS + Math.random(); 
  let x = CX + (r * Math.cos(ANGLE));
  let y = CY + (r * Math.sin(ANGLE));
  let z = - ( p / DENSITY );
  let v = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );

  tube.vertices.push( v );

  tube.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( p, p-offset[0], p-offset[2] ) );
  tube.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( p, p-offset[2], p-offset[1] ) );

  // update calculation parameters
  CX += ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 0.1;
  CY += ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 0.1; 
  RADIUS += ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 0.1;
  if ( RADIUS < MIN_RADIUS ) RADIUS = MIN_RADIUS;
  if ( RADIUS > MAX_RADIUS ) RADIUS = MAX_RADIUS;
  ANGLE += INCREMENT;

}
```

I have it working where the vertices are calculated once as a static mesh which is then uploaded to the GPU and animated towards the camera.  No interactivity, yet.  https://codepen.io/jarrowwx/pen/gKraVm

Next step is to make it infinite.  Which means I'm going to have to do it differently.

One way I could do it is to keep a sufficient number of vertices in an array, calculating new vertices as I go, enough to make up for the distance traveled since the last time step.  Then, once a second or so, rebuild the face array, and rebuild the scene.  But that means once a second, there will probably be a noticeable lag.

But because all the vertices are calculated, it makes sense to do all the work on the GPU and avoid the task of transferring data in the first place.

How would one go about building this data structure on the GPU so that the data never has to be transferred from CPU to GPU?  And then, once you have pulled that off, how do you continuously extend it as the camera flies through it?

Comment: Maybe this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-achieve-this-material-effect-gif-image/1270/10?u=prisoner849) will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe these are helpful? [cubes](https://www.vertexshaderart.com/art/zd2E5vCZduc5JeoFz), [sphere](https://www.vertexshaderart.com/art/p9pecgaEBJ3kz5r7g), [torus](https://www.vertexshaderart.com/art/mNBny7JXpBGwQnMwG)

Comment: In WebGL 1, you could do the processing in one draw call and store your results in a float texture. Or in WebGL 2 using transform feedback.

Comment: If you can read french, there is a tutorial explaining how to create an infinite tunnel with a finite number of vertices that you just send to the GPU once:
http://tolokoban.github.io/webgl-experiments/tunnel.html
Click on the likns with the words "le résultat" to see the steps of construction.